# the meaning of "western order" in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"Fake news" was not a term many people used 18 months ago, but it is now seen as one of the greatest threats to democracy, free debate and the Western order. ([source](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/0/fake-news-exactly-has-really-had-influence/))

Answer (score 1):

The Western order in that sentence refers to the international framework of economic and political relationships that constitute the "Western world", that is, the non-Russian and Chinese capitalist world.